# Can I use Tensorflow on Orange pi 4G IOT with Ubuntu?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, iot, 4g, orange-pi

I am trying to build an imaging system and I want to use Tensorflow with Orange pi 4G. Does anyone know if there are limitations, is this possible?

As I can see Orange PI 4g iot is still not compatible with Ubuntu but I hope it will be in the near future. Any information you could give  me i will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Official CI server for Tensorflow has some [nightly builds](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/) with python wheels for raspberry pi armv7l, it is not officially supported by tensorflow yet, they officially support only 64-bit architectures so far, but I managed to get yolo-keras working on "orange pi pc plus" using their nightly build wheel file.
You can also find the scripts they used for building the wheel (actually it's cross-built using a docker container) in directory `tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/ci_build` inside source code.

Some people also provided [guides for native building](https://github.com/rezaxdi/tensorflow-on-orangepi-zero/blob/master/GUIDE.md), but it generally requires more effort to get it to work.

I suggest you start by trying the python wheel file for tensorflow v1.8.0 for raspberry pi armv7l architecture, [found here](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/301/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl).